# Array to elements javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function that makes output like this:

```
 (9) [1, "...", 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, "...", 19]
```

But i want output like this(just remove commas and brackets)

```
1 "..." 9 10 11 12 13 "..." 19
```

What I want to do is convert that first array to elements like second example because I need to use it with handlebars and cant find a way how to do it.
But i want to keep format of that first just need to remove that array.

```
{{#each pageArray}}
            <li class="paginator-item">
                <a href="{{this}}" class="paginator-itemLink">{{this}}</a>
            </li>
{{/each}}
```

Function is:

```
<script>
            function pagination(currentPage, nrOfPages) {
                var delta = 2,
                    range = [],
                    rangeWithDots = [],
                    l;

                range.push(1);

                if (nrOfPages <= 1) {
                    return range;
                }

                for (let i = currentPage - delta; i <= currentPage + delta; i++) {
                    if (i < nrOfPages && i > 1) {
                        range.push(i);
                    }
                }
                range.push(nrOfPages);

                for (let i of range) {
                    if (l) {
                        if (i - l === 2) {
                            rangeWithDots.push(l + 1);
                        } else if (i - l !== 1) {
                            rangeWithDots.push('...');
                        }
                    }
                    rangeWithDots.push(i);
                    l = i;
                }

                return rangeWithDots;
            }


            pageArray = pagination({{ current }}, {{ pages }});
            console.log(pageArray);
        </script>
```

Comment: Just take the last element `elm`, and create an array from `1` to `elm`?

Comment: So it uses an ellipsis on every 8 items? Not understanding the issue at hand

Comment: Well handlebars works only with second example not with first i need to convert that first example to look like the second so handlebars can take it.
Simple i will edit answer to what i want

Comment: @CertainPerformance i cant this is pagination and i need that dots too.

Comment: Best to post your *real* expected output the first time you post the question, otherwise there will be confusion and useless comments/answers :)

Comment: @CertainPerformance i feel lost in javascript but simply i just want to remove commas and brackets from that first output thats all. This output what i made like second example is exactly what i want to see.

Comment: I think you are looking for `.join(" ")` in the array... but it's not clear what exaclty you want by reading your question

Comment: The [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method turns an array into a string by combining all the elements. Whatever you pass it will become the separator between each element. Ie, `[1,2,3,4,5].join(" then ")` will return `1 then 2 then 3 ...`

Comment: Wow join(" ") really done what i need. Thank guys for your effort. And sorry for not clear question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Just change last function to this.

```
pageArray = pagination({{ current }}, {{ pages }}).join(" ");
```